# Push notification in Ionic app using Amazon SNS

Tags: ionic-framework, push-notification, amazon-sns

I am trying to implement Ionic push with Amazon sns.I am not understanding where to start from . Please guide...

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [amazon sns with ionic framework](http://t.yc.sg/post/102663623041/amazon-sns-with-ionic-framework-part-1-android)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [phonegap-plugin-push plugin](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push) to display the notifications inside your ionic app.  It is not the easiest thing to setup, but there is [comprehensive guide](https://medium.com/@dhaval/integrate-sns-push-notifications-with-cordova-ios-app-664e0c4c3a18#.4owox3ajc) that can help you on your way.